# how to give drop shadow for adobe air window?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

I am developing adobe air application.

I am trying to give drop shadow around window in WindowedApplication skin class, But it is not taking the shadow.

I want to give shawdow behind window as seen in Microsoft link application.

Any suggestion or solution are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set none and true in your app descriptor XML to get a transparent and chromeless native window.

Then you would have to add any window decorations you might need back, and add the drop shadow to the top most parent sprite of your window (probably also making the parent sprite's origin and size inset within the native window to account for the drop shadow area).

You can try [this example](http://casario.blogs.com/mmworld/2010/08/adding-a-drop-shadow-to-a-custom-chrome-window-in-air-2.html) as well

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, I tried a workaround giving like below in skin  <s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="21" right="21" top="21" bottom="21">
  <s:fill>
   <!--- @private -->
   <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill"/>
  </s:fill>
  <s:filters>
   <fx:Array>
    <s:GlowFilter color="0x000000" alpha="0.4" blurX="40" blurY="40"/>
    <s:DropShadowFilter color="0x000000" alpha="0.4" blurX="40" blurY="40"/>
   </fx:Array>
  </s:filters>
 </s:Rect> is this the right way?

Comment: Check the example I just added on my answer